# Defining concrete associatedtype but I still can't use protocol as variable

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

I would like to use `SendMessageUseCase` as a variable type, for example `var sendMessageUseCase: SendMessageUseCase` but I can't.

I keep getting the error `Protocol 'SendMessageUseCase' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Which obviously I understand the error but it doesn't make sense.

In `SendMessageUseCase` I have defined my associated type using `Where` clause which means technically the compiler should be able to infer, since I have explicitly defined `Input` and `Output` to be `SendMessageUseCaseInput` and `SendMessageUseCaseOutput` respectively.

```
protocol UseCaseInput {}
protocol UseCaseOutput {}
protocol UseCase : AnyObject {
    associatedtype Input: UseCaseInput
    associatedtype Output: UseCaseOutput
    
    func execute(input: Input, _ completion: (_ output: Output) -> ())
}

struct SendMessageUseCaseInput : UseCaseInput {
    var text: String
}

struct SendMessageUseCaseOutput: UseCaseOutput {
    var response: String
}

protocol SendMessageUseCase: UseCase where Input == SendMessageUseCaseInput, Output == SendMessageUseCaseOutput {
    
}

final class TestSendMessageUseCase : SendMessageUseCase {
    func execute(input: SendMessageUseCaseInput, _ completion: () -> ()) {
        
    }
}

// Why this doesn't work?
var sendMessageUseCase: SendMessageUseCase = TestSendMessageUseCase()
```

can `SendMessageUseCase.Input` be anything else other than `SendMessageUseCaseInput`? I don't think so which is why I think it should be inferd. But obviously I am wrong and can't understand why.

Comment: "can `SendMessageUseCase.Input` be anything else other than `SendMessageUseCaseInput`?" No, but that doesn't change the fact that your protocol still has an associated type requirement.

Comment: Of course I understand, I just thought the compiler could infer it or there was a way to implement it. But I guess I was wrong, thanks.

Comment: Use the `some` keyword.

Comment: @Jessy Thank you although opaque type did work for the variable it doesn't work for arrays which makes sense. I can live with this limitation for now. I understand it is a limitation of swift and there are some talks to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from @Jessy I was able to come to a temporary solution.

Adding `some` to the `sendMessageUseCase` variable would allow us to use `opaque` type but there is still a limitation as you can not have an array.

There are some talks to implement this but as of now (May, 28 2022) it still hasn't been implemented.

```
protocol UseCaseInput {}
protocol UseCaseOutput {}
protocol UseCase : AnyObject {
    associatedtype Input: UseCaseInput
    associatedtype Output: UseCaseOutput
    
    func execute(input: Input, _ completion: (_ output: Output) -> ())
}

struct SendMessageUseCaseInput : UseCaseInput {
    var text: String
}

struct SendMessageUseCaseOutput: UseCaseOutput {
    var response: String
}

protocol SendMessageUseCase: UseCase where Input == SendMessageUseCaseInput, Output == SendMessageUseCaseOutput {
}

final class TestSendMessageUseCase : SendMessageUseCase {
    func execute(input: SendMessageUseCaseInput, _ completion: (SendMessageUseCaseOutput) -> ()) {
        
    }
    
}

var sendMessageUseCase: some SendMessageUseCase = TestSendMessageUseCase()
```

If anyone is interested here are the forum threads

[Lifting the “Self or associated type” constraint on existentials](https://forums.swift.org/t/lifting-the-self-or-associated-type-constraint-on-existentials/18025)

[ [Sema][AST][WIP] Support existentials with concrete assoc. types #21576](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/21576)  (PR is closed)